# how can i use and manage logs [Log4j] java?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm new in Framework's *logging*  and i need your advice.
I develop a java EE application and i want to integrate logs in it, I see that I can use **RollingFileAppender** to save my logs in files. But what i want to do is to manage those logs, filter them by categories and create a statistics. 
I know that if i use **JDBCAppender** i can do such things but this solution is not recommended because of using a lot of resources . 
any recommended solution ?

H-Raf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Logging I would recommend to use [SLF4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and try the new [Log4J 2 binding](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html).

To analyse log files from several nodes there are tools such as [Splunk](http://de.splunk.com/) (commercial) or [GrayLog](https://www.graylog.org/) (Open Source with commercial support).

Comment: thanks ser, i see a tutorial which someone melange a **log4j** and **SLF4j** and really i didn't understand why he did this. but i will try to see **GrayLog** too :) thanks